# How to grab specific group from ansible inventory and use it in playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I need to grab specific sub group from my inventory file and use it in ansible playbook correctly.

```
all:
  children:
    development:
      children:
        ntp_servers:
          hosts:
            ntp01:
            ntp02:
        services:
          children:
            chatbot:
              children:
                app:
                  hosts:
                    chatbot-app01:
                    chatbot-app02:
                db:
                  hosts:
                    chatbot-db01:
                    chatbot-db02:
            dice:
              children:
                app:
                  hosts:
                    dice-app01:
                    dice-app02:
                db:
                  hosts:
                    dice-db01:
                    dice-db02:
                    dice-db03:
                redis:
                  hosts:
                    dice-redis01:
                    dice-redis02:
```

For example I want to grab app subgroup of chatbot group. 
Can anyone give example playbook how to reference chatbot.app group?

I used like this but this seems to be wrong statement.

```
- hosts: chatbot:app
  roles:
    - chatbot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not directly possible to achieve what you are trying to achieve. The problem you currently have is that the hostgroup names `app` and `db` are being repeated, and this will skew your results.

Firstly you will need to ensure you use unique group names. For example:

```
all:
  children:
    development:
      children:
        ntp_servers:
          hosts:
            ntp01
            ntp02
        services:
          children:
            chatbot:
              children:
                chatbot_app:
                  hosts:
                    chatbot-app01:
                    chatbot-app02:
                chatbot_db:
                  hosts:
                    chatbot-db01:
                    chatbot-db02:
            dice:
              children:
                dice_app:
                  hosts:
                    dice-app01:
                    dice-app02:
                dice_db:
                  hosts:
                    dice-db01:
                    dice-db02:
                    dice-db03:
                dice_redis:
                  hosts:
                    dice-redis01:
                    dice-redis02:
```

Then you can look at referring to parent/child groups as you see fit. Using the example in your question, you can do:

```
- hosts: chatbot_app
  roles:
    - chatbot
```

The same can be done for all of your groups (development, ntp_servers, services, chatbot, dice, etc)